# Is there a keyboard shortcut in VSCode that allows me to navigate to the beginning/end of the current function scope?

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

Sometimes I'll be navigating inside of a Python function or class whose implementation spans across many lines and I'd like to navigate to the beginning or end of the scope without having to visually scroll and identify where it ends.

Thanks in advance

I've tried `ctrl + shift + \` which really only works for navigating between brackets, so not all that helpful in my case where I'm using python, where logical blocks aren't scoped by brackets but by indentation

Comment: You could assign a shortcut to the "Go to Parent Fold" command, and hit it a few times until you get to the beginning of the function. Not sure about the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `Go To Symbol` command (which is bound by default to <kbd>ctrl/cmd</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd>) to search for the function and then jump to it, which would take you to the top, and then from there, if you want to jump to the bottom, use the `Expand Selection` command (which is bound by default to <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>alt/opt</kbd>+<kbd>right</kbd>) to expand until you've selected the whole function, and then use the down or right arrow key to move to the end of the selection.